# SQLite string contains other string query

Tags: sql, sqlite

How do I do this?

For example, if my column is "cats,dogs,birds" and I want to get any rows where column contains cats?

Comment: edit your question with a set of sample data. It's hard to determine exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Seems like you can also use the CONTAINS command but its implementation doesn't appear to be standardized and I couldn't get it to work using SQLite; however, there is documentation for it at [Oracle][1] and [Microsoft][2] and it was supposedly faster according to another [thread][3] but you may need to use another type of SQL instead of SQLite

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Using LIKE:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE column LIKE '%cats%'  --case-insensitive
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't suitable where the string you're searching for is variable or contains a special character such as `%`.

Comment: if "cats" is a field from an other table, you could use `'%'||table2.field||'%'`as the like criteria

Answer (score 133):

While `LIKE` is suitable for this case, a more general purpose solution is to use [`instr`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr), which doesn't require characters in the search string to be escaped. Note: [`instr` is available starting from Sqlite 3.7.15](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_15).

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE  
 WHERE instr(column, 'cats') > 0;
```

Also, keep in mind that `LIKE` is case-*insensitive*, whereas `instr` is case-*sensitive*.

Comment: Which means that your minSdkVersion should be 21 (5.0-Lollipop)

Comment: @WilliamEntriken In my own test, `instr(...)` is a little bit faster (0.32s vs 0.34s). You can use `.timer on` in SQLite to measure the execution time.