# Data-structure to put in full English dictionary to return quickly all possible word completions from String in android

Tags: java, android, string, dictionary

### Problem description

I should somehow load a full English dictionary (at least 650 000 words, possibly over a million) into a data structure that makes it fast and easy to find back all possible ways to end a `String` of letters in a **particular** order. You should also be able to find if the String is an actual word.

The way this (game) is setup is that you continually narrow down the possible words by appending new letters to the String. This probably could make it sequentially faster to search as the game goes on and more letters are added. However, if some sort of hash-map way of implementing this is used meeting the constraints that would of course be ideal. I would rather not have the user feel that the game is (a tiny bit) slow(er) in the beginning as there are still a lot of possibilities to complete the `string`.

### Simple example

These are just examples to make it clear what I am trying to do and that it becomes clear that it could be implemented as a narrowing search:

> string: app

```
String[] possibleWords = dataStructure.getCompleteAbleWordsWith("app");
//possibleWords = ["app", "apps", ..., "apple", "apples", ...];
```

> string: appl

```
String[] possibleWords = dataStructure.getCompleteAbleWordsWith("appl");
//possibleWords = [..., "apple", "apples", ...];
```

### Requirements

- Should work on cheap android devices as quickly as possible, size of the application matters less but should still be fair to the user.
- Should be able to handle large dictionaries of over 650 000 words
- Should be able to return list of possible words
- Should be able to tell if a string is actually a word (could of course check if string[] is length 0)

since the dictionary is static, does not change at runtime, I would rather have it saved in a compact and easily search-able form or even better have the whole data structure object already be in machine code or something.

### What I tried:

1. I implemented a hash-map that read in all words from the dictionary and search was extremely fast and balanced for complete words. However, this approach felt wrong if I want to do this for all words and their partial forms with a key value pair that indicated true it was a word and false if not for example.
2. Looked into multi-way trees but I felt that there could be betters ways since the tree would be very, very wide and unbalanced.
3. Thought about [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498844/sqlite-string-contains-other-string-query), using the LIKE keyword. I have next to none experience with databases right now, so I have no clue of the performance of those, in specific on android devices.

Any ideas to get me on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I recommend looking into tries](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). When learning about them we were told this was a good example of a use for them.

This is from the link:

> A common application of a trie is storing a predictive text or autocomplete dictionary, such as found on a mobile telephone. Such applications take advantage of a trie's ability to quickly search for, insert, and delete entries

Comment: @MosheCarmeli, There is an implementation [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706) which may be useful for you.