# SQLITE: select rows where a certian column is contained in a given string

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which has a column named "directory" which contains strings like:

```
c:\mydir1\mysubdir1\
c:\mydir2
j:\myotherdir
...
```

I would like to do something like

```
SELECT FROM mytable WHERE directory is contained within 'c:\mydir2\something\'
```

This query should give me as a result:

```
c:\mydir2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite string contains other string query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498844/sqlite-string-contains-other-string-query)

Comment: My question is the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just found that sqlite has a function **instr** that seems to work for my purpose.

Not sure about the performance, though.