# How to check if a string contains a value in the database?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have a database with:

```
John Smith - 103

Jane Doe - 287

Mike Smith - 371
```

And I have a string like:

```
"Let's see the value of John Smith in the database"
```

I need a way to check if this string has any of the names in it and get the value associated with the name.

How can I do this in sqlite?

This is not the same as the question linked, it's the inverse. I have the string and I am looking for a pattern that matches it.

If I did:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column LIKE '%string%'
```

I would get nothing.

It would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE string LIKE '%column%'
```

But I don't think this can be done like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite string contains other string query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498844/sqlite-string-contains-other-string-query)

Comment: Read up on `LIKE`.

Comment: You are pointing to the reverse problem. LIKE would solve if I had the pattern and was looking the string that contains it. But I have a string and I am trying to find a pattern that matches it.

Comment: What is `John Smith - 103`? Is it a value of 1 column or 2 columns?

Comment: Two columns, one column is John Smith, the other is 103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sqlite instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr):

> **instr(X,Y)**
>
> The instr(X,Y) function finds the first occurrence of string Y within string X and returns the number of prior characters plus 1, or
>   0 if Y is nowhere found within X. Or, if X and Y are both BLOBs, then
>   instr(X,Y) returns one more than the number bytes prior to the first
>   occurrence of Y, or 0 if Y does not occur anywhere within X. If both
>   arguments X and Y to instr(X,Y) are non-NULL and are not BLOBs then
>   both are interpreted as strings. If either X or Y are NULL in
>   instr(X,Y) then the result is NULL.

Something like:

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE instr("Let's see the value of John Smith in the database",name) <> 0
```

You might want to `lower()` or `upper()` all strings to handle case.

Comment: That's it, I didn't know the instr function. Thank you very much.