# How to check if a string is in my Room ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is my Table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_data")
data class UserData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "matched_users") var matchedUsers: ArrayList<String>
)
```

I want a `Boolean` query to see if `matchedUsers` contains the passed-in string:

```
@Dao
interface UserDataDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE :matchId IN matched_users")
    fun matchedBefore(matchId: String): Boolean
}
```

Obviously my query is wrong, but how can I achieve this?

PS: If `ArrayList` is not possible, can I use `List<>` or `Set<>`?

Comment: How are you storing array list in room , are you using typeconverter ?

Comment: I don't understand your entity class , matchedUsers is autogenerated ? then whats the use of your entity

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to Room. This is all I have at the moment. I just want to store an `ArrayList<String>` of strings, and then be able to query to see if the arraylist contains a string. @ManoharReddy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `matchedUsers` is autogenerated , take another property in `UserData` class , `id` an Int which will be `@PrimaryKey` and auto generated .

You can not directly store an arraylist in room , you need to use a `TypeConverter` .
See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083865/6478047) on how to use type converter .

Your complete arraylist of string will be stored as single string after using type converter . You can then write a [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3498858/6478047) to check if the string contains a substring .

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my table. Do you know if `Set<String>` can be used instead of `ArrayList<String>`? Or do they both need `TypeConverter`?

Comment: Both would need a type converter